# Can I resample (ffill) pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this, with a MultiIndex over `('timestamp', 'id')`:

```
                 value
timestamp   id
2020-03-03  A    100
2020-03-03  B    222
2020-03-03  C    5000
2020-03-04  A    NaN
2020-03-04  B    1
2020-03-04  C    NaN
2020-03-05  A    200
2020-03-05  B    NaN
2020-03-05  C    NaN
2020-03-06  A    NaN
2020-03-06  B    20
2020-03-06  C    NaN
```

I want to forwards fill (timewise) on `value` so that the dataframe is populated with the most recently available data item, i.e. the DataFrame becomes:

```
                 value
timestamp   id
2020-03-03  A    100
2020-03-03  B    222
2020-03-03  C    5000
2020-03-04  A    100
2020-03-04  B    1
2020-03-04  C    5000
2020-03-05  A    200
2020-03-05  B    1
2020-03-05  C    5000
2020-03-06  A    200
2020-03-06  B    20
2020-03-06  C    5000
```

Is there any easy way using resampler?

Comment: Can you try `df.sort_index(axis=0, level=0, sort_remaining=False).fillna(method='ffill').astype(np.int64)`

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the second level and ffill , then reindex like original:

```
df.sort_index(level=1).ffill().reindex(df.index)
```

---

```
                value
timestamp  id        
2020-03-03 A    100.0
           B    222.0
           C   5000.0
2020-03-04 A    100.0
           B      1.0
           C   5000.0
2020-03-05 A    200.0
           B      1.0
           C   5000.0
2020-03-06 A    200.0
           B     20.0
           C   5000.0
```

Comment: this works well if there is an initial value (as there was in my example) to forward fill for each item in level 1. If there isn't, then a value from A can spill over into B or B into C. But I can work around this. So thanks for answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `stack` to arrange the data in a correct 2D representation for filling (column-wise) and then unstack back to the original format. This treats columns (i.e. indexes) separately as opposed to rolling over data values, which is the case in the other solution given.

```
a = ['2020-03-03','2020-03-04','2020-03-05', '2020-03-06']
b = ['A', 'B', 'C']
c = ['value1', 'value2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b]), columns=c)
df.loc[('2020-03-03', slice(None)), 'value1'] = np.array([100, 222, 5000])
df.loc[('2020-03-04', 'B'), 'value1'] = 1.0
df.loc[('2020-03-05', 'A'), 'value1'] = 200.0
df.loc[('2020-03-06', 'C'), 'value1'] = 20
df['value2'] = df['value1']
df.loc[('2020-03-03', 'C'), 'value2'] = np.nan
df

                 value1  value2
timestamp   id
2020-03-03  A    100     100
2020-03-03  B    222     222
2020-03-03  C    5000    NaN   # <- OBS!
2020-03-04  A    NaN     NaN
2020-03-04  B    1       1
2020-03-04  C    NaN     NaN
2020-03-05  A    200     200
2020-03-05  B    NaN     NaN
2020-03-05  C    NaN     NaN
2020-03-06  A    NaN     NaN
2020-03-06  B    20      20
2020-03-06  C    NaN     NaN
```

Using `df.unstack().fillna(method='ffill')` gives

```
            value1             value2
            A     B     C      A     B     C
timestamp
2020-03-03  100   222  5000    100   222   NaN
2020-03-04  100   1    5000    100   1     NaN
2020-03-05  200   1    5000    200   1     NaN
2020-03-06  200   1    20      200   1     20
```

This can be reverted with `.stack()` to the original format again.

Comparing this to `df.sort_index(level=1).ffill().reindex(df.index)` the difference is in the last column where since 'C' start with an `NaN` the value from 'B' of 1 is rolled into the start of 'C' for 'Value2'.